# MySql time query results in 838:59:59

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL database i do have a TIME field containing the value "17:27:00"
When i do query this database with the query from a bash script:

```
    SELECT tcTransactionTime FROM 2price_data;
```

I do get the result "838:59:59".
I know that this value is the Mysql time limit, but the strange thing is that the time value in the database is correct and within these limits.

I becomes even more strange when i execute the query via phpmyadmin it will display the correct format "17:27:00".

Anyone any clues what might cause this strange behaviour?
Thanks!

Gr Johan

Comment: Can we see proper DDLs?

Comment: What do you mean with DDL's? (sorry, this is my first question on this platform).

Comment: Create and insert statements.